Armatures Presets folder created at startup
Every time Blender starts up, this folder is created on Drive C on Windows. If I access different drives during work process, the same folder is created on each of those drives. Do you know what is causing this and how can it be turned off?


I've never seen that here. Maybe created by a third-party addon? - There seems to be one on Gumroad called "Armature Layer Presets".

Yeah, that's definitely not a built-in feature. Check your addons. Looking through the code of the addon @JohnEason posted, it does create an armature layer preset folder but it goes to bpy.utils.resource_path("USER") which is where your addons and scripts in \AppData\Roaming would be. Not at the root C:\ directory.

Thanks friends. I started to eliminate the plugins one by one and it appeared that the latest update of Auto Rig Pro has a new path system, where every path defaults to /Armatures Presets, /Bones etc. So it does not go to the Appdata\Roaming and creates these folders in the drive root in case they do not yet exist.

Thanks friends. I started to eliminate the plugins one by one and it appeared that the latest update of Auto Rig Pro has a new path system, where every path defaults to \Armatures Presets, \Bones etc. So it does not go to the Appdata\Roaming but creates these folders in the drive root in case they do not yet exist.
Thank you @john-eason and @jakemoyo
